# PHP: how to return multi dimension array from recursive function

Tags: php, recursion

This is my code,
and I need your help to understand it.

```
<?php $tree = array(
array(
    'name' => 'Item-1', 
    'children' => array()),

array('name' => 'Item-2', 
    'children' => array(
    array('name' => 'Item-2-1', 
        'children' => array()),
)),
array('name' => 'Item-3', 
    'children' => array(
    array('name' => 'Item-3-1', 
        'children' => array()),

    array('name' => 'Item-3-2', 
        'children' => array(
        array('name' => 'Item-3-2-1', 
            'children' => array()),

        array('name' => 'Item-3-2-2', 
            'children' => array()),

        array('name' => 'Item-3-2-3', 
            'children' => array(
            array('name' => 'Item-3-2-3-1', 
                'children' => array()),
        )),
    )),
)),
```

);

What i need is one recursive function, which will return all names (name).
For example:

```
Item-1
Item-2
Item-2-1
Item-3
Item-3-1
Item-3-2
```

........

My attempt but it just doesn't seem to work for me

```
function tree($tree){ 
    foreach ($tree as $key =>$value) { 
         foreach ($value as $key=>$value){ 
            echo "$value<br>"; } 
    echo "<br>"; } }
```

Comment: You need our help in making you understand your own code?

Comment: I would say that you should first start reading about PHP. You are not having a problem with some code, you look like haven't even tried to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RecursiveArrayIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`

```
$ai = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($tree));
echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $ai as $value ) {
    echo $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
Item-1
Item-2
Item-2-1
Item-3
Item-3-1
Item-3-2
Item-3-2-1
Item-3-2-2
Item-3-2-3
Item-3-2-3-1
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GRS20d)

Answer (score 0):

From http://snipplr.com/view/10200/

```
// Recursively traverses a multi-dimensional array.
function traverseArray($array)
{ 
    // Loops through each element. If element again is array, function is recalled. If not, result is echoed.
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    { 
        if(is_array($value))
        { 
            traverseArray($value); 
        }else{
            echo $key." = ".$value."<br />\n"; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Also see [Sum integers in 2d array using recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688902/sum-integers-in-2d-array-using-recursion)